# Reading text file with fscanf not working as intended

Tags: c, scanf

I ahve to read a file with numbers and as well as som text, but when i try to read each line of the file it skips the \n after the first line of numbers and reads two lines as one instead of two seperate ones.

I want to strictly use the fgets and the fscanf for this.

```
struct lakemedel
{
    char namn[MAXORD];
    int forpackningar[PAKETSTORLEKAR];
    int antalForpackningar;
    int saldo[PAKETSTORLEKAR];
    int antalSaldo;
};
typedef struct lakemedel Lakemedel;

Lakemedel lakemedelRegister[MAXANTAL];

    printf("Skriv in fil du vill anvanda: ");
    scanf(" %s", lasFilnamn);
    int i = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int nl = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(lasFilnamn, "r");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {        
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s", lasLakemedelRegister[i].namn)==1)
        {
            lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar = 0;
            lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo = 0;
            printf("fff");
            while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].forpackningar[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar]) == 1)
            {
                printf("aaa");
                lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar++;                
            }
            while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].saldo[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo])==1)
            {
                lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo++;
            }
            /*for (lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar = 0; lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar == 1; lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar++)
            {            
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].forpackningar[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar]);
            }
            for (lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo = 0; lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo < PAKETSTORLEKAR; lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo++)
            {            
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].saldo[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo]);
            }*/
            (*pAntalLakemedel)++;
            i++;
        }
```

Here's and exmaple of a file i want to read:

```
Hello
25 40
2 5
Hi
85 41
2 3
```

I expect each line if numbers to be read into an array, but the reason why it isn't done os because it jumps the newline character somehow and read until the next text line.

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXANTAL 10000
#define MAXORD 20
#define PAKETSTORLEKAR 10
#define FILNAMNSTORLEK 20

struct lakemedel
{
    char namn[MAXORD];
    char forpackningar[PAKETSTORLEKAR];
    int antalForpackningar;
    char saldo[PAKETSTORLEKAR];
    int antalSaldo;
};
typedef struct lakemedel Lakemedel;

void lasFil(Lakemedel lasLakemedelRegister[], int *pAntalLakemedel, char lasFilnamn[]);
void skrivUt(Lakemedel skrivLakemedelRegister[], int pAntalLakemedel);

int main()
{
    Lakemedel lakemedelRegister[MAXANTAL];
    char filnamn[FILNAMNSTORLEK];
    int antalLakemedel = 0;
    int val;
    lasFil(lakemedelRegister, &antalLakemedel, filnamn);
    //printf("%d", lakemedelRegister[0].forpackningar[0]);
    while (1 && val != 8)
    {   
        printf("\n\n2-Skriva\n8-Avsluta\n\n");
        scanf(" %d", &val);
        switch (val)
        {
        case 1: //Registrera
            break;     
        case 2: //Skriva ut
            skrivUt(lakemedelRegister, antalLakemedel);
            break;
        case 3: //Söka
            break;
        case 4: //Lägga till storlek
            printf("hello");
            break;
        case 5: //Ändra saldo för läkemedel
            printf("hello");
            break;
        case 6: //Avregistrera läkemedel
            break;
        case 7: //Varningar
            printf("hello");
            break;
        case 8: //Avslutar programmet
            printf("Avslutar Programmet...");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        } 
    }

    return 0;
}

void lasFil(Lakemedel lasLakemedelRegister[], int *pAntalLakemedel, char lasFilnamn[])
{
    printf("Skriv in fil du vill anvanda: ");
    scanf(" %s", lasFilnamn);
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(lasFilnamn, "r");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {   
        while(fscanf(fp,"%s", lasLakemedelRegister[i].namn)==1)
        {
            lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar = 0;
            lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo = 0;
            printf("ff");
            while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].forpackningar[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar]) == 1)
            {
                printf("aa ");
                lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar++;                
            }
            while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].saldo[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo])==1)
            {
                printf("gg ");
                lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo++;
            }
            /*for (lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar = 0; lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar == 1; lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar++)
            {            
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].forpackningar[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar]);
            }
            for (lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo = 0; lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo < PAKETSTORLEKAR; lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo++)
            {            
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].saldo[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalSaldo]);
            }*/
            (*pAntalLakemedel)++;
            i++;
        }
    fclose(fp);
    }
        printf("\n\n%d\n", *pAntalLakemedel);
        printf("%s\n",lasLakemedelRegister[0].namn);
        printf("%d\n",lasLakemedelRegister[0].antalForpackningar);
        printf("%d\n", lasLakemedelRegister[0].antalSaldo);
}
```

Comment: The loop `while (fscanf(fp, "%d", ... ) == 1)` will continue to scan integers until the next string stops it. It will scan all four of those integers you show in the input file. So the following `%d` format scans won't read anything, and return `0`. Note that newlines and other white space characters are of *no consequence* to `scanf` when using `%d` and `%s` format specifiers.

Comment: Okay, yes that seems logical. But is there any way to make the fscanf stop at that new line, or modify the .txt file to read in correctly? I've looked for hours for a solution to suing the fscanf this way.

Comment: Read each line with `fgets` then apply `sscanf` to that string. But if the format of the file is fixed, why do you have `while` loops for `%d`? One thing you can do, is to read the next character also, but it is an unreliable way (there might be a trailing space on a line). The sure way is to place the *number of elements* at the start of each batch.

Comment: In order to read the numbers i would have to change the array for those to `char`, which is not really what i would want. The reason for the `While` loops is to increase the number of an int in order to keep count on how many numbers i have read from text file to array. How would i do if i was to read next character to the `fscanf` ?

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf(" %s", lasFilnamn);` (and similar statements)  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current cases, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using the `%s` and/or `%[...]` input format specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input. This also avoid a buffer overflow and Undefined behavior

Comment: OT: regarding: `fp = fopen(lasFilnamn, "r");
    if(fp!=NULL)`  the second statement should be checking for an error condition and if an error has occurred, then `{ perror( "fopen failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }` so both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use meaningful variable names.  Names like: `int f = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int nl = 0;` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: when posting a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: the posted snippets of code contains no functions, is missing the needed header files, etc.  Post a [mcve] so we can help you

Comment: I posted the full code which should be able to be executable for further examination:)

Answer (score 0):

According to the C standard, fscanf, on success, will return the number of items read from the input stream (which can be less than the number requested if a read error occurs, or end of file is reached). If a read error occurs, or end of file is reached before any data is read, EOF is returned.

So, as others have said, the following while loop will not stop at a newline character. It would only stop when the input stream encounters a non integer character or EOF is reached.

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].forpackningar[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar]) == 1)
{
   printf("aa ");
   lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar++;                
}
```

The proper way to read two numbers from an input stream using fscanf is as follows:

```
numIntsRead = fscanf(fp, " %d %d", &intVar1, &intVar2);
// Use numIntsRead to ensure both numbers were actually read
```

You would want to drop the two while loops, and simply call the code above twice for each set of 2x ints to be read.

P.S. Note the leading space in the format specifier. As per the standard, space in the format specifier can match *zero* or more white space characters in the input. This will ensure correct parsing if there is leading whitespace in the file.

Comment: That seems to work, but what if my .txt file would have varying number of ints on each row, i wouldn't constantly looke for two int on each row. How do i looka for a variable amount of ints on each row and save them?

Comment: You actually in that case would use a while loop like you originally had, with one specific addition:

`while ( fscanf ( fp, " %d [^\n]", &lasLakemedelRegister[i].forpackningar[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar]) == 1)

{

   printf("aa ");

   lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar++;

}

if ( fscanf ( fp, " %d", 
&lasLakemedelRegister[i].forpackningar[lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar])

{

   printf("aa ");

   lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar++;

}`